# Visual Force Page Not Displayed On SalesForce1 Community Version Only

Tags: visualforce, javascript, salesforce1-app, dynamic-visualforce

I applied my custom VF page to a global action, works perfectly internally, however, when using the community the page does not display. The page has been checked for displaying on mobile, permission have been set for all users and even tried to redirect the URL but no luck. The same page works on desktop though.

When debugging the page, I noticed the following error:

GET https://sandbox-campus.cs16.force.com/apex/AccountViewMobile?id=001f000000H…FrameOrigin=https%3A%2F%2Fsandbox-campus.cs16.force.com&sfdcIFrameHost=web 503 (Service Unavailable)

The path should be sandbox-campus.cs16.force.com/Office/apex/ or .../Office/

Could anyone explain why the page does not display on the community version of Salesforce1 app?

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce 1 Mobile has not yet been implemented in Communities. Don't expect it until at least Summer 14 (Safe Harbor) or later. I was told during Salesforce 1 Week that some of the issues SF had to overcome before they could implement this feature was support for different SF User ID's when changing Orgs when visiting a different community. I recall there were other issues, but that was the most significant.

The reason the path is different than you may have expected is because VisualForce pages are hosted on a different server than your SF instance is; including your sandbox.